# Unkown Z-Index issue with CSS

Tags: css

I have the following CSS working on an element:

```
               .box {
                width: 400px;
                height: 60px;
                -moz-border-radius: 30px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
                border-radius: 30px;
                -moz-background-clip: padding;
                -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                background-clip: padding-box;
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #dfdfdf 0%, #e9e9e9 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #dfdfdf 0%, #e9e9e9 100%);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #dfdfdf 0%, #e9e9e9 100%);
                background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #dfdfdf 0%, #e9e9e9 100%);
                position: relative;
                top: 100px;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
            }
```

For whatever reason, this is hiding an element behind it. The element behind it should have a high z-index. I can not identify what CSS property might becuase this element to have a high z=index.

And ideas?

Incase anyone is wondering, the element that is getting hidden is a Primeface's Dock.

Comment: Can you add some html? or provide us with a JSFiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle? html structure? need! more! info!

Comment: Pay attention to the nesting of these elements, or else ordering will dictate the layering. z-index applies to sibling elements, not cousins or ancestors.

Comment: The usual way to find what's causing the problem is to delete lines of code, a few at a  time, until you pinpoint what's messing it up and THEN find a workaround.

Comment: have you set `position:absolute` to the other element???